# Constructing Strings using Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, character-encoding, set, regular-language

Assuming you have a a set E = {a,b}, and you have a superset E* consisting of all possible combinations of a, and b in E. How do you construct an expression for a String that has number of a's divisible by 3?

Comment: no, it is from a book. Do you know how to work this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
/^(b*ab*ab*ab*)+$/
```

Examples:

```
abbb => N
bbb => N
aaab => Y
ababbbba => Y
aaabba => N
bbbaaaabbbabbbba => Y
 => N
```

Comment: Is there another way to define this language that did not include actually having a's in there as you have it?

Comment: Maybe `/^((b*a){3}b*)+$/`? I'm not sure what you are asking.